# Browser-sync reload constantly

Tags: javascript, browser-sync

I am creating project with JS, HTML, CSS and I am trying to makes my workflow faster and easier, so I decide to install browser-sync to help with auto-reloading page during coding process. And that would be great solution but browser-sync constantly after 30-60 sec reloading my page, what is annoying because during debugging when I change something in google chrome dev tools, like css properties, browser reload and changes gone. This is how I start browser-sync

```
browser-sync start --server --files .
```

And this is my bs-config.js

```
module.exports = {
"ui": {
    "port": 3001,
    "weinre": {
        "port": 8080
    }
},
"files": ["./css/*.css", "./scripts/*.js", "./*.html"],
"watchEvents": [
    "change"
],
"watchOptions": {
    "ignoreInitial": false
},
"server": false,
"proxy": false,
"port": 3000,
"middleware": false,
"serveStatic": [],
"ghostMode": {
    "clicks": true,
    "scroll": true,
    "location": true,
    "forms": {
        "submit": true,
        "inputs": true,
        "toggles": true
    }
},
"logLevel": "info",
"logPrefix": "Browsersync",
"logConnections": false,
"logFileChanges": true,
"logSnippet": true,
"rewriteRules": [],
"open": "local",
"browser": "default",
"cors": false,
"xip": false,
"hostnameSuffix": false,
"reloadOnRestart": false,
"notify": true,
"scrollProportionally": true,
"scrollThrottle": 0,
"scrollRestoreTechnique": "window.name",
"scrollElements": [],
"scrollElementMapping": [],
"reloadDelay": 0,
"reloadDebounce": 0,
"reloadThrottle": 0,
"plugins": [],
"injectChanges": true,
"startPath": null,
"minify": true,
"host": null,
"localOnly": false,
"codeSync": true,
"timestamps": true,
"clientEvents": [
    "scroll",
    "scroll:element",
    "input:text",
    "input:toggles",
    "form:submit",
    "form:reset",
    "click"
],
"socket": {
    "socketIoOptions": {
        "log": false
    },
    "socketIoClientConfig": {
        "reconnectionAttempts": 50
    },
    "path": "/browser-sync/socket.io",
    "clientPath": "/browser-sync",
    "namespace": "/browser-sync",
    "clients": {
        "heartbeatTimeout": 5000
    }
},
"tagNames": {
    "less": "link",
    "scss": "link",
    "css": "link",
    "jpg": "img",
    "jpeg": "img",
    "png": "img",
    "svg": "img",
    "gif": "img",
    "js": "script"
}
```

};

I didn't add any configs to it. I was trying to find solution but nothing help.

What I want is to reloading page only when I make and save changes to .htm, .css, .js files and I thought that is default behavior for browser-sync.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I've searched online but can't see what's causing the issue. Clearing the cache like most people suggest does nothing to help.

Comment: I removed refresh from index html.  That stoped refreshing constantly.